# Can't use function return value in write context, PHP can't figure out why

Tags: php, sql

This is my code :

PHP:

```
    if(isset($_COOKIE("cookie_roof_angle")) && isset($_COOKIE("cookie_roof_direction")))
    {
        $roof_angle                     = intval($_COOKIE("cookie_roof_angle"));
        $roof_direction                 = $_COOKIE("cookie_roof_direction");
        $solarsell_page05_rendement    = mysql_query("SELECT value FROM solarsell_page05_pvgis WHERE angle = $roof_angle AND azimut = " . $roof_direction. "  ");
        echo $solarsell_page05_rendement;
    }

    else
    {
        echo "no values";
    }
```

I'm getting this error message :

**Fatal error: Can't use function return value in write context in C:\xampp\htdocs\Development\phpFunctions.php on line 19**

After some searching around on the web & stackoverflow.com, I found out it may be caused by the `isset` function, could anyone please explain if this is the problem and why?
If this is not the problem, maybe I did something wrong in my code part, but I can't figure out why.

The Cookies where both set when I got the error.

Sincerly,
Harmen Brinkman.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Syntax error:

`$_COOKIE["cookie_roof_angle"]` instead of `$_COOKIE("cookie_roof_angle")`